# 13 Month Old or 13-Month-Old?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, compounds

I have just installed Grammarly and it showed up something which i am not sure of.

It corrected '13 month old' to '13-month-old'.

The context is

> I ask because my 13-month-old God daughter seemed like she was a little resentful towards another child who was visiting at the same time.

Which would be correct, and why?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the context. I know the sentence itself isn't great.

Comment: relevant: [How do hyphens modify the meaning of “n-month-old”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59083/how-do-hyphens-modify-the-meaning-of-n-month-old)

Comment: Never depend on software for spelling, punctuation, and least of all grammar— they find typos or common mistakes, but do not dictate correctness, especially as different style guides vary somewhat on hyphenation. Also see *[Ways to write “2000 year old”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/69742)* and *[How do hyphens modify the meaning of “n-month-old”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/59083)*; *[Hyphenating measurements](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/208040)*, and *[Pluralization rule for “five-year-old children”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1366)* among others.

Comment: It's spelled goddaughter.

Answer (score 7):

General rule of thumb with compound adjectives like this is to hyphenate them if they are made up of words which modify the base adjective and couldn't be used independently. The best way to gauge this is to write the sentence out with each word making up the adjective individually and see if they all still make sense:

> My 13 God daughter

Obviously doesn't make sense

> My month God daughter

As above

> My old God daughter

Makes sense, but doesn't convey the meaning you intended.

"old" here is the base adjective; 13 and month are modifying it, so you hyphenate. 13-month-old.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the explanation. I must not have been at school the day that was taught.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this approach to compound adjectives is a regular part of any curriculum, but I definitely think it should be!

Comment: It is a very simple method.

Comment: @Terry What's more likely is that your school never taught it. Government schools aren't known for being high quality.

Comment: It's also important to recognize that "My goddaughter is 13 months old", you do *not* hyphenate. Lots of people hypercorrect these and hyphenate at all times, because they don't recognize the purpose of the hyphens is to convert the phrase "13 months old" into a single word that can be used as an adjective to modify "goddaughter".

Comment: A good point, and a sad one to have to make. :(

Answer (score 4):

The basic mnemonic rule, which is called the [Eleven-Year-Old Boy Rule](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/209603/15299), is

- one-word modifiers **precede** the noun they modify
- modifiers of more than one word **follow** the noun they modify.

One way of making a modifier of more than one word into a one-word modifier is to [hyphenate it](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/76255/15299).
Like *an eleven-year-old boy* versus *a boy eleven years old*. Of course, that's just in writing.
In speech hyphens are inaudible so we just use the word order.

Comment: I might add that pre-nominal modifiers **never** take plural endings, even if they are always plural. For instance, the correct phrase is _shoe store_, even though shoes always come in pairs -- *_shoes store_ is simply wrong.

Comment: *Never* seems to me a bit strong; but maybe that's only because I took an arts degree and grew up in Alabama during the Civil Rights movement.

Comment: There are different spelling variants used for 'nine days wonder', according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nine_day_wonder).

Comment: I assume nouned (deleted) usages retain the hyphens? 'He has the mind of an eleven-year-old.'

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, both options are acceptable - hyphens or no hyphens.

However, I opt for the hyphenated version because it has a clear meaning and makes it an adjective, which presumably is what it is intended to be.

See sumelic's link, as that has a very good explanation.