# What is the proper way to address quantities in a list of materials?

Tags: parentheses

I'm working on a list of materials and quantities. Should parentheses be used around the quantities?

> Example List:
>   4 4 foot ladder
>   7 6 inch nails
>   6 apples
>   9 oranges
>
> (4) 4 foot ladder
>   (7) 6 inch nails
>   (6) apples
>   (9) oranges

If parentheses are used for the quantities in the list, then should they be used around all quantities in the document?

> Example:
>   Please provide (6) apples and (7) 6 inch nails.

I automatically use parentheses for clarity but my use is now being questioned as excessive and unnecessary...

I'd like to understand the proper use and reasoning. How should they be used?

Comment: I would suggest *6x apples; 7x 6-inch nails [or 6" nails]*, it is clearer than parentheses and is more readable. However, use of parentheses is definitely better than without them

Comment: My habit when specifying is generally to create a table for the information, especially since that allows you to create a column for the price to be quoted in. If the information is in the run of text however I would  say 'Please supply: 4' ladder x 4 No, 6" nails x 7 No, Cox's Orange Pippins x 6 No.' Actually I'd say 'Please provide your price to supply....' or 'Please supply: 4' Ladder x 4 @ [insert supplier's previously quoted price].  Always make sure the price is explicit when ordering-- Generally, put the object first, then the number- it makes for fewer error in fulfilling orders.

Comment: Probably relevant:  [Eleven-Year-Old Boy Rule](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/302751/50044)

Comment: Look at the format used in recipes. It's a columnar paradigm of N x 2.

Comment: @JohnLawler Speak of the devil! My earlier comment was a link to your answer. :)

Comment: *four 4-foot ladders, seven 6-inch nails, six apples, nine oranges*; to emphasize the divisions, semicolons could be used in place of commas.

Comment: or (if you want to use parentheses), *four (4) 4-foot latters, ...*; but this looks confusing.

Comment: The problem with using "x" is you may need to talk about 2x4s or 4x8 sheets. I've seen 8qty 2x4 fir, and 8 of 2x4 fir also.

Answer (score 2):

Everything about a list is a matter of personal choice guided by only two rules, both of thumb:

A) Nothing in a list needs to follow any standard rule of punctuation, grammar, capitalization, punctuation or, really, even spelling

B) Whatever form is chosen needs to be clearly understandable to anyone likely to need to read it; store-keepers, project managers or anyone else.