# high throughput, high-throughput or high through-put

Tags: hyphenation

All these three forms, high throughput, high-throughput or high through-put, are used in the scientific community by Google Scholar searching. Where is the hyphen should be? Is there a specific context for their using?

Thank you!

Comment: Related question, [How do hyphens modify the meaning of “n-month-old”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59083/how-do-hyphens-modify-the-meaning-of-n-month-old) and [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word).

Comment: @Rathony, thank you for your comment and the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fact that you have a compound word (throughput) within the structure confuses things. I'll use another example to clarify the rule* then we go back to this

*it's not a "rule" strictly speaking, since - as you yourself realized through Google Scholar texts - there are many approaches.

Let's take the example `sparkling white wall` versus `sparking-white wall`
The hyphen is used when `sparkling-white` is used as an adjective for wall (in other words, we mean that the color/shade of the wall is not merely "white", but "sparkling white". Without the hyphen you would essentially have two adjectives, `sparkling` and `white` - i.e. "the wall is sparkling and the wall is white". It's subtle, I know.

On your example, it depends on whether you use the word as an adjective or noun. Here are two examples to demonstrate:

```
I have noticed a high throughput in the production line
```

vs

```
I have noticed a high-throughput result in the production line
```